# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

It failed to resolve: com.google.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.0.0.I've included all the necessary dependencies.Also,I've enabled the Google Button Login in the firebase.Still,the problem exists.I'm unable to resolve the firebaseui error.

1. build.gradle(Module:app)

   ```
       apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

       android {
           compileSdkVersion 26
           buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
           defaultConfig {
               applicationId "com.example.application.moneyapp"
               minSdkVersion 16
               targetSdkVersion 26
               versionCode 1
               versionName "1.0"
               testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           }
           buildTypes {
               release {
                   minifyEnabled false
                   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
               }
           }
           productFlavors {
           }
       }

       dependencies
               {
                   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
                   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
                   })
                   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
                   compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.1'
                   compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.0.1'
                   compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
                   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
                   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
                   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.4.2'
                   compile 'com.google.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.0.0'
                   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
                   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
                   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
                   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
                   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
                   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
               }

       apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```
2. build.gradle(Project:Sample)

   ```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
           // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
           // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
   }

   allprojects
           {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           maven{
               url "https://maven.google.com"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   I am getting this following Error..I know that this Question is already in Stack Overflow but it does not resolve my problem.
   [Messages Gradle Sync is showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUN4N.png)

In the old sample answers,solution is to install Google Repository and Google play Service in SDK Manager..Even after installing them to the latest version,I am getting the Same Error..Please resolve my problem..
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/941

Comment: still the same problem :(

Comment: Try to import the single modules of firebase-ui

Comment: Clean up your project and resync

Comment: Even after importing single module,couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: already done that..clean and resync..

Answer (score 0):

There is no all-inclusive FirebaseUI package, so you need to specify the individual library that you require.

From the [FirebaseUI installation documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md#installation):

> FirebaseUI is published as a collection of libraries separated by the Firebase API they target. Each FirebaseUI library has a transitive dependency on the appropriate Firebase SDK so there is no need to include those separately in your app.
>
> In your app/build.gradle file add a dependency on one of the FirebaseUI libraries.
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
>     compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
>
>     // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
>     compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.1.0'
>
>     // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
>     compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
>
>     // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage 
>     compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.0'
> }
> ```